# Inserting data to database from dropdown menu whose data was imported from another database

Tags: php, mysql, forms

i have created dropdown menu where options are inputted from database, however, i want the chosen option to be inputted to another database.

```
<?php
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

              unset($idex, $ExName);
              $idex= $row['idex'];
              $ExName = $row['ExName']; 
              echo '<option value="'.$idex.'">'.$ExName.'</option>';

   }  

  ?>
      <div id="sub">
      <input type="submit" name="Submit1" value="Submit" >   
    </div>
         </select>

         <?php

    if(isset($_POST['Submit1'])){ 
            if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                } 

        $sql = "INSERT INTO students (Ex1)
        VALUES ('$ExName')";

        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
        }
        $conn->close();
            ?>
```

Can someone please give me advice how to do it? the record is submitted, but it is last row in dropdown list, not he chosen one.

Comment: You must use $_POST['your_select_name'] instead of $ExName in $sql. I don't see your select open tag name here.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you fetch the select's value that will come from post.

You may want to add this just above the sql query you have written.

```
$ExName =  $_POST['exnamessel'];
```

also  i can't see select definition like

```
<select name="exnamessel">
```

just before you print the options and outside of the while loop.